# How to do one select two query with join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table as follows:

```
- tblEmployee

    employeeID    | Name   
    10            | sothorn
    20            | lyhong        
    30            | sodaly    
    40            | chantra    
    50            | sangha   
    60            | bruno

 - tblSale

        ID | employeeID   | employeeSaleID
        1  | 30           | 10
        2  | 10           | 40   
        3  | 50           | 20
```

I would like to select from tableSale and join with tblEmployee result that:

```
1 | sodaly  | sothorn
2 | sothorn | chantra
3 | sangha  | lyhong
```

Comment: Do you need an answer on how to do this with CodeIgniter Active records? Or is this just an SQL question? If it's the latter, please update your tags. If it's the first, please provide more information. How did you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply select all rows of the `tblSale` table, and join `tblEmployee` table twice:

```
SELECT s.ID, e1.Name, e2.Name
FROM tblSale s
INNER JOIN tblEmployee e1
    ON e1.employeeID = s.employeeID
INNER JOIN tblEmployee e2
    ON e2.employeeID = s.employeeSaleID
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample query on your data.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b74ca/5/0

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Here you need to use inner join to get data from both tables.

```
select 
id, e1.name as name1, e2.name as name2 
from 
tblSale s, tblEmployee e1, tblEmployee e2 
where 
s.employeeID=e1.employeeID 
and 
s.employeeSaleID=e2.employeeID 
order by 
s.id
```

- Thanks

Comment: Wow, why are all your answers "Try this: XXX -- Thanks"?

Comment: Of course it's personal opinion, but instead of teaching to fish, you just gave the fish. Your usage of "Try this" also indicates that are not even sure yourself, though, and just propelled the answer artillery that may fit or may not.

Comment: Of course I get it. Just as I get that you are not willing to invest a bit more time to show what the error was, and instead present a turnkey answer. The questioner will not learn anything, and come back with basically the same question next time. About the tone of your comment: You asked me what's wrong with the style, I take the time to explain it to you, and then you bark back in an aggressive style that totally doesn't fit your "peaceful" attitude you try to sell on your about-page. Interesting.

Comment: Ok. I understand & try to give answer in brief & easy enough to understand by questioner properly. Thanks for help & guide to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple

QUERY

```
SELECT
    tblSale.ID,
    l.Name,
    r.Name
FROM tblSale
INNER JOIN tblEmployee l On l.employeeID = tblSale.employeeID
INNER JOIN tblEmployee r ON r.employeeID = tblSale.employeeSaleID
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b74ca/8)

OUTPUT

```
| ID |   LNAME |   RNAME |
|----|---------|---------|
|  1 |  sodaly | sothorn |
|  2 | sothorn | chantra |
|  3 |  sangha |  lyhong |
```

Comment: Try this but didn't success

Answer (score 1):

just join the employee table twice, once to employeeID, once to employeeSaleID